# tkinter.Button retains depressed appearance after exiting event handling

Tags: python, button, tkinter, messagebox

Trying this again...I have a Python programmed GUI in which the pressed Button retains a depressed look after the event handler exits.  The event handler made use of a messagebox.  Normally, this does not happen.  Here is an example that recreates the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# post a message
def post_message(event):
    messagebox.showinfo("Sample Messgebox", "close this and look at button")

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Press Me")
b.bind("<Button-1>", func=post_message)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `blind` with the event `Button-1`, you aren't using the main event of the button. You can active the main event of the button with the argument `command`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def post_message():
    messagebox.showinfo("Sample Messgebox", "close this and look at button")

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Press Me", command=post_message)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: should have added that use of command was not the interface I wanted

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why your code isn't working properly, since I'm fairly new to Py, I managed to rewrite it to work with minimal changes.

**Solution 1**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# post a message
def post_message():
    messagebox.showinfo("Sample Messgebox", "close this and look at button")

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Press Me", command=post_message)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What I changed:

no more `bind()` as this caused problem, instead the function is called by adding `command=` option while declaring Button object,

also notice that command option doesn't provide function called with `event` parameter, so this had to be removed or else errors would occur.

Another workaround, this time it works with `bind()` just fine!

**Solution 2**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# post a message
def post_message(event):
    root.after(0, lambda: messagebox.showinfo\
    ("Sample Messgebox", "close this and look at button"))

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Press Me")
b.bind("<Button-1>", post_message)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I used `master.after(time_in_ms, callback_func)` to tell the program that it should run a given func after the given time, here 0ms so ASAP.

Why is that lambda inside after? Lambda is a dynamic, not-named function. After takes a reference to the function you want called, so you can't directly give it parameters.

To do so, like in this example, set up a lambda that will be refrenced.

When it finally gets called, that lambda func will then call the actual function you wanted to call giving it the parameters it needs.

*If you don't know yet how lambdas work, I know you're confused right now, so read more on them here, they're super-useful: [Lambdas explained](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_functions_lambda.php)*

*For great source of info on tkinter, please visit [effbot.org Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)*

Comment: Thanks.  This is a good work around for what I think is an internal bug